# Is there any way to calculate Christoffel symbols of the second kind for spherical polar coordinates directly using metric tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

> Determine the Christoffel symbols of the second kind for spherical polar coordinates.

From, $$ds^2=dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2\sin\theta d\phi^2$$
We can easily calculate the metric tensor $g_{ij}$ and get,

$$
g_{i j}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & r^{2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & r^{2} \sin ^{2} \theta
\end{array}\right]
$$
and
$$
g^{i j}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & r^{-2} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \left(r^{2} \sin ^{2} \theta\right)^{-1}
\end{array}\right]
$$

I knew the relation between Christoffel symbols of the second kind and metric tensor,
$$
\Gamma_{\alpha \beta}^{\mu}=\frac{1}{2} g^{\mu \lambda}\left(\frac{\partial g_{\lambda \alpha}}{\partial x^{\beta}}+\frac{\partial g_{\lambda \beta}}{\partial x^{\alpha}}-\frac{\partial g_{\alpha \beta}}{\partial x^{\lambda}}\right)
$$

To calculate those symbols, we need to choose $\alpha,\beta$ and $\mu$ carefully. But is there any way to obtain those directly by using the matrix $(g_{ij})$? Because $\Gamma_{i j}^{1},\Gamma_{i j}^{2}$ and $\Gamma_{i j}^{3}$ seems to be related with the matrix.

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\Gamma_{i j}^{1}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -r & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -r \sin ^{2} \theta
\end{array}\right]\\
&\Gamma_{i j}^{2}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \frac{1}{r} & 0 \\
\frac{1}{r} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -\sin \theta \cos \theta
\end{array}\right]
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
\Gamma_{i j}^{3}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{r} \\
0 & 0 & \cot \theta \\
\frac{1}{r} & \cot \theta & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$

Comment: Not sure how you did it but you can compare the results with [this](http://einsteinrelativelyeasy.com/index.php/general-relativity/34-christoffel-symbol-exercise-calculation-in-polar-coordinates-part-ii).

Comment: Aha, nice blog post. Thanks, @KurtG.

Comment: That link is about a 2-dimensional spherical surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Not to be confused with what is done here.

Comment: @falamiw: typo metric

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Smart observation, but also not quite.

What you can do is consider the dot product of basis and implicitly differentiate that.

$$\vec e_r.\vec e_r=1$$

Differentiate the above with $r, \theta$ and $\phi$ for the symbol relations.

You can get further ones by considering the dot product of radial vector with the other basis vectors like azimuth or polar and differentiating that too.

## Calculating $\Gamma_{r \theta}^{\theta}$:

WE have:

$$ e_{\theta} \cdot e_{\theta} = r^2$$

Differentiating with $r$:

$$ (\partial_r e_{\theta}) \cdot e_{\theta} =r  \tag{2}$$

Now to actually get the Christoffels from the above, a small observation must be done. We have that:

$$ \partial_r e_{\theta} = \Gamma_{r \theta}^r e_r +  \Gamma_{r \theta}^{\theta} e_{\theta} + \Gamma_{r \theta}^{\phi} e_{\phi}$$

Dot both side with $e_{\theta}$:

$$ \partial_r e_{\theta} \cdot e_{\theta} = \Gamma_{r \theta}^{\theta} e_{\theta} \cdot e_{\theta}$$

Or,

$$ \frac{(\partial_r e_{\theta}) \cdot e_{\theta}  }{e_{\theta} \cdot e_{\theta}} =  \Gamma_{r \theta}^{\theta}$$

Now , put $2$ in this and use that $e_{\theta} \cdot e_{\theta} = r^2$. Done!

---

I use an identity from page-275 of Pavel Grinfeld's Tensor Calculus book,

[image]

$Z_i^{\alpha}$ is the basis on the surface, $S^{\gamma}$ are the parameters of the surface ( the chart coordinates).

Comment: If someone could format this that'd be nice ( I wrote on phone)

Comment: I think adding an example would be a great help to grasp the answer @Beautifullyirrational. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @falamiw here u go

Comment: You need to use the contravariant basis as well, like this $$\Gamma^j_{hk}=\mathbf{e}^j\cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{e}_h}{\partial x^k}$$

Comment: Why tho? Afaik christoffel is just the components of the basis with the coordinates, so directly reading off here should be okie. @ContraKinta

Comment: In polar coordinates $e_i=(\hat{r},r\hat{\theta})$ and $e^j=(\hat{r}, \frac{\hat{\theta}}{r})$. So for example $$\Gamma^\theta_{r\theta}=e^\theta\cdot\frac{\partial e_\theta}{\partial r}=\frac{1}{r}$$ Try doing this calculation using your recipe.

Comment: Oh, I see why you pointed it out. But it can be remedied quiet easily @ContraKinta

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational can you give a reference for the formula next to (2)?

Comment: Hmm isn't it just derivative of the dot product? @janmarqz coud you be more specific which aspect of the formula do you find confusing?

Comment: @Beautifullyirrational  The covariant derivative $$\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j=\Gamma^s{}_{ij}\partial_s,$$ is not the same to $$\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x^i\partial x^j}.$$

Comment: @janmarqz See page-175, Ex 223 Pavel Grinfeld Tensor Calculus. I have used a simplification

Comment: Why the coordinates that use falamiw are affine?