# Why we need to show that $dx^i$ is a contravariant vector to prove metric tensor is a covariant symmetry tensor of rank two

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

> The metric tensor $g_{ij}$ is a covariant symmetry tensor of rank two.

I know the proof which complete into 3 steps:

- Show that $dx^i$ is a contravariant vector
- Show that $g_{ij}$ is a covariant tensor of rank two (By showing $\bar{g}_{ij}=g_{kl}\frac{\partial \bar x^i}{\partial x^k}\frac{\partial \bar x^j}{\partial x^l}$)
- Show that $g_{ij}$ is symmetric

The last two steps can make sense, but I couldn't understand why we need to show the first step here?

Comment: What book you use? Please give that

Comment: Sorry for late response. [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gcF3Aza_o6hu7gGwl2IkZjrX3NtOexog/view?usp=sharing) is the chapter from where we have taught metric tensor. You can get the problem under the solution of **THEOREM 3.1**, page-01. @Beautifullyirrational

Comment: And I just noticed you have deleted your answer from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4514913/736159) post. From my last view, the answer was helpful. Is there any issue with that answer?

Comment: One person had asked for justification for one the steps. I need to search a bit to do it. But, I couldn't at the time so I deleted.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to prove anything as this is simply a definition. However, this relies on knowing what a manifold is, what a tangent bundle is, and what a tensor product is. A good reference for this is Lee's *Smooth Manifolds*.

The metric tensor is by *definition* a covariant tensor $g$ of rank 2 over a smooth manifold $M$, say of dimension $m$.

Now given a chart $x$ on the manifold then writing out the local expression of the metric in this chart will give you the transformational law you indicate. In older treatments this is usually taken as a definition.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Actually, We are not introduced with Manifold yet. We are only introduced with curves, Surface in space and first fundamental form. And the question arise from introductory tensor calculus course. I think, I couldn't write your answer in my course. It will be a great help if you answer it from tensor calculus perspective @MoziburUllah